# How to scroll down to bottom of the frame in Chrome using web driver in java

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver

I want to scroll down to the bottom of a frame in the page. I am currently using this. It is flaky and does not work most of the time.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  actions.moveToElement(<Myclass>.clickOnFrame(className));
        actions.click();
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
        actions.build().perform();
```

Is there any more to add on this, or any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

for scrolling you can use JavascriptExecutor as:

scroll down

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0,250);");
```

scroll up

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0,-250);");
```

and apparently you can switch to the frame before it using `switchTo().frame(<frame identifier here>)` in webdriver.